# Eror exucting script with python 3.5 but working fine with 3.8

Tags: python, syntax

I'm running the following script in Python 3.5 :)

```
def series_to_fac_details_xml(s):
    return fac_details_xml_template.format(**s)

for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    details = series_to_fac_details_xml(row)
    with open(fr"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Afgeleverd\{row['Output']}.xml", "w") as f:
        f.write(fac_doc_template.format(fac_details=details))
```

the error it gives you is "invalid syntax"..
However, with python 3.8 it works just fine.

I have to run Python 3.5 because UiPath only supports python versions >3.6

Could you please help?

Comment: Python 3.5 does not support f-strings yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
with open(fr"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Afgeleverd\{row['Output']}.xml", "w") as f:
```

You can't use f-strings in python 3.5 because they were added in python 3.6. Use another string formatting method instead like `format()`.